# how to put white space and change date format in View on MVC ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC application and using razor syntax.

In this application I am giving comment facility.

Currently the comments look like...

```
P Moris9/15/2012 5:40:44 PM
Test comment 1 


P Moris9/15/2012 5:40:44 PM
Test comment 2 


P moris9/15/2012 5:40:45 PM
Test comment 3
```

Now, I wan to put space between Name of the comment owner and the datetime.
As well How do I convert dateTime in to

dd-MMM-yy hh:mm tt ?

The Comment should be look like ...

> P Moris       17 Sept 2012 05:45 PM.
>
> Test comment 1

(I cant give more than one space in above sample...its automatically remove the space.)

How should I ?

My code in View is

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div id="OwnerName">
    
         <span class="EmpName"> @Html.ActionLink(item.Owner.FullName, "Details", "EMployee", new { id = item.OwnerId }, new { @style = "color:#1A6690;" })</span>
         
           @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentDateTime)
         
        </div>
                       
     
        
        <p class="CommentP">
           @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentText)
        </p>
        
        <br />
        

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put an `&nbsp;` between the comment author name and the creation date:

```
<div id="OwnerName">
    <span class="EmpName">
        @Html.ActionLink(item.Owner.FullName, "Details", "EMployee", new { id = item.OwnerId }, new { @style = "color:#1A6690;" })
   </span>
   &nbsp;
   @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentDateTime)
</div>
```

And in order to [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) the comment date you could decorate your view model property with the [`[DisplayFormat]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt}")]
public DateTime CommentDateTime { get; set; }
```

And if for some reason you are not using view models and cannot modify your entities you could format it in the view:

```
<div id="OwnerName">
    <span class="EmpName">
        @Html.ActionLink(item.Owner.FullName, "Details", "EMployee", new { id = item.OwnerId }, new { @style = "color:#1A6690;" })
   </span>
   &nbsp;
   @Model.CommentDateTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt")
</div>
```

Another possibility is to write a custom display template (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/CommentDate.cshtml`):

```
@model DateTime
@Model.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt")
```

and then pass the custom display template name to the `DisplayFor` helper:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentDateTime, "CommentDate")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cant use @Model.CommentDateTime , I have to use  `@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentDateTime)
`

Comment: In this case you could decorate the `CommentDateTime` property on your view model with the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute which allows you to specify the desired format. Another possibility is to write a custom display template.

Comment: I didnt use View Model in my application, should I add it ?

Comment: Yes, using view models is the correct way to go in ASP.NET MVC. You should not be passing your domain entities to the views.

Comment: I am going to follow the last option which you have suggest...but I am lil confused abt stpes to follow...means I supposed to write only below code in cshtml class ?  `@model DateTime
@Model.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt")`

Comment: @user1668543, yes that would be enough. You could of course add span tags or whatever if you need additional markup around the date.

Comment: one more thing, I am unable to post new question, each time above question details come when I click on 'Ask Question' button. I am doing something wrong or did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

For  white space  use  below  code

```
@{
  @:  &nbsp;&nbsp;
}
```